# iOS UIAlertController Dark Theme

Tags: ios, themes, uialertcontroller

I'm working on an app for iOS with a dark theme and I want to use a `UIAlertController`. However, the white alert looks out of place. Would it be against the Human Interface Guidelines even on a dark themed app to use a dark themed `UIAlertController` (when I say dark themed alert all I mean is switching the white background to a dark grey and the text to white this also includes the buttons).

Assuming it's not against the guidelines how would I go about achieving this? I can't seem to find a theme for the `UIAlertController` that would allow this.

Answer (score 21):

With iOS 13, Apple provides Dark Mode. But if your App theme doesn't match with Device Theme, you can set your view controller's theme.

For eg, My Device Appearance is Dark Mode, and my App is always in light mode. But the popups using UIAlertController are following Device Theme, Dark theme, and a black popup over my white screen doesn't match.

**Solution #1: Inline Solution**

While creating the UIAlertController, I can set its theme

```
alert.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = UIUserInterfaceStyleLight;
```

**Solution #2: Support for Whole App**

In you AppDelegate, set  the theme for window

```
self.window.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = UIUserInterfaceStyleLight;
```

This will cause all the popups to use light theme.

*Note: UIAlertView won't use the dark/light theme if you set its overrideUserInterfaceStyle property. 
Also, don't forget to add `if #available(iOS 13.0, *)` check before setting the property, as it is available only in iOS 13+*

Answer (score 0):

Well, customizing `UIAlertView`/`UIAlertController` is not possible, but there's a plenty of custom Alert implementations on CocoaControls, just take a look there. It's more a philosophical question; I guess it doesn't really violate anything.

Comment: Is it common to just use the default white alerts regardless of the general app theme or should I really invest the time into making a custom one?

Comment: System alerts are preferred as people are used to how they appear. Howerer lots of apps use custom alerts, mostly keeping the theme light-coloured.